# Can I use use Hashcode to directly lookup a value in a C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have numerous instances of Dictonary, the contents of these dictionaries change frequently and have on the order of 100 or so entries (sometimes much less). 
I need to query this dictionary VERY often. 
I'm not quite sure yet, but i think my dictionary look ups are cumulatively becoming expensive, and are adversely affecting my performance (which is a key concern).

Could I be caching the hashcode of my string keys

```
 int hc = MyStrKey.GetHasCode();
```

and then looking up the corresponding value in the Dictionary via the hashcode directly (when I can)? 
If it is even possible, is it not recommend, is it worth it in speedup?

By the contents changing frequently, I mean I am adding and removing entries from the dictionary over time.

Could another course of action be using int keys instead, where I cache associations of my actual string keys to unique (to the specific dictionary) int keys and use a Dictonary instead?

Am I potentially barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: `Am I potentially barking up the wrong tree here?` that just depends how your query looks like. Please edit your post to show a query.

Comment: I don't think Dictionary access times can get progressively worse in such a way to be noticeable, given the same state otherwise. I bet something else goes wrong.

Comment: If you want to query that dictionary very often, write your own hashtable. I tried it and it got faster by a single-digit factor.

Comment: @usr I would be really interested to see how you implemented that

Comment: @Mishax you loose many abstractions, basically. You need to make private members public, change callers to use different usage patterns and use power-of-two tables sizes to cut out the slow modulus operator. None of that is transparent, it requires extreme changes both to the dictionary as well as to the callers.

Comment: The problem with those hashes is that they collide frequently. So your program will *sometimes* not work correctly.

Comment: Heslchaher: I might be miss-understanding your question about my queries, essentially i am doing look up via string with values.TryGetValue(name, out valueEntry);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it would make much difference, but you could do some timing tests to find out.

You could write a simple immutable wrapper class for String that caches the hash code, and use that as the key type, for example:

```
public sealed class StringKey: IEquatable<StringKey>
{
    public StringKey(string key)
    {
        Contract.Requires(key != null);

        _key = key;
        _hashCode = key.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _hashCode;
    }

    public bool Equals(StringKey other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return (_hashCode == other._hashCode) && string.Equals(_key, other._key);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        return obj is StringKey && Equals((StringKey) obj);
    }

    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return _key;
        }
    }

    private readonly string _key;
    private readonly int    _hashCode;
}
```

However, like I said, I doubt this will make much difference.

Comment: If I did cache the hashcode, how would i query the dictionary with it instead of the actual key?

Comment: You wouldn't cache the hash code, you would use instances of `StringKey` as the keys for the dictionary instead of strings. But you'd have to keep the keys around for looking things up; if you keep recreating the `StringKey` objects then they'd be doing a GetHashCode() every time you create one. Come to think of it, the `Dictionary` itself probably caches the hash codes so it doesn't need to keep calling `GetHashCode` for the string keys that it contains - but it will call `GetHashCode` for the keys you use to lookup values.

Comment: Yes, I've just looked at the implementation of Dictionary (using Reflector) and when it stores keys, it calculates the hash code once only for each key. When it looks up keys, it calculates the hash code of the target key once only and then uses that to find the correct value. So I really don't think you will get much speedup (if any) from any kind of caching you could do.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the hash code isn't the *only* item necessary to look up an item from a dictionary (or a HashTable for that matter).  It only makes it faster to find the *bucket* that the item is in.

It's certainly possible (and not uncommon) for two unequal items to have the same hash code.  The dictionary uses the hashcode the find the bucket, then compares the items in that bucket to the given key by using `Equals`.

Think of it as organizing Legos in buckets by color - knowing the *color* of the Lego you need helps you find it *sooner*, but you still need to know the exact piece you need to find the *right* piece.

So could you look up items by hash code in a dictionary?  Possibly, but you'd still need the original value to be certain you got the *right* item.

Comment: Forgive me, what I meant was that if caching the hashcode, could it be be used to speed up the look up. But from the post so far, it probably wont help much if at all. It also seems like using an int as a key vs a string also wont make much difference?

Comment: @Ryan if your Dictionary implementation is making use of HashCodes to do the lookup then no it won't matter, the library will calculate the HashCode if it's an Int32 or a String - check it out try to evaluate the expression `9.GetHashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not quite sure yet, but i think my dictionary look ups are cumulatively becoming expensive

First make your measurements and find out precisely what problem you are trying to solve. Doing lookups in dictionaries with 100 key/value pairs should be very fast.

As for using ints or Strings as keys, beware the hashcode calculation of these items is not defined in the FCL APIs and is implementation specific. It's impossible to make a general statement.

Comment: Haven't made exact measurements yet, just comparing against when i reduce the amount of queries, and when just just doing an index table look up. Table look up is of course MUCH faster (but i can't use that in practice). And when reducing the number of queries, i do get a considerable speed up in the containing component usage.

Comment: Forgot to mention i am using mono packaged with Unity4.2, mono develop version 2.8.2.

Comment: Measurement is of course needed, its just to compare I would have to implement the alternative, which would be time consuming. But there may be no other way of knowing.